# backorder functionality not working in magento2.3.2

Tags: magento2

I am using magento2.3.2. My website product backorder functionality is not working on the frontend.

I have done all steps below:

1. configure backorder in catalog->inventory- and set the Backorders - allow quantiy o and notify customer
2. php bin/magento indexer:reindex
3. php bin/magento cache:clean
4. php bin/magento cache:flush

I have run all the commands but my backend changes do not reflect in the frontend.

Before it was working fine but after migration and enabling varnish cache then issues happen.

So let me know how I can solve this.

Answer (score 0):

To flush the Varnish cache of your Magento store on the command line you can use

```
/data/web/magento2path/bin/magento cache:flush full_page
```

This will purge the Varnish cache of the local Varnish instance.